# Rails. How can I make .sum method faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to calculate total value for column `:total_value` in Order model. I try to do:

```
Order.where("created_at > :day", {:day => 10.day.ago}).where(user_id: 3, state: 'collected').sum(:total_value)
```

It works for me. But... Is there any possibility to do it faster? 
Should I add indexes for `:total_value` and `:created_at` columns. Does it make a sense?

Comment: Why not give that a shot? Testing on the actual data will beat theoretical differences *every time*

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN output look like?

Comment: I just try to find a faster way. I have not very big count of orders but when I do this request for collection of users it takes a time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really that well aware of Rails internal optimizations, but the thing that first comes into my mind is combining the where clauses into one instead of two. Now it has to first create a result set for the first where and then apply other where on that set (assuming that Rails doesn't optimize it already).

Creating index for total_value makes no sense since you aren't looking for anything based on that column.

Comment: For OP's code, Rails will execute a single query with a single `WHERE` clause. (When an ActiveRecord query expression has multiple `.where`s, they are combined with `AND`.)

Comment: You can also just select the columns you want and are relevant by passing the select option in the query

Comment: @NikitaSingh `.select` is ignored in a `.sum` query—Rails will only SELECT the SUM(s).

Comment: What about `:created_at` column index - does it make a sense?